# CouchDB in-memory implementation

Tags: couchdb

Is there a mock backend for CouchDB, i.e. same REST interface and semantics but purely in-memory? We have a testsuite that runs each test on a pristine database every time (to be reproducible), but running against real database could be faster.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean running against a *mock* database?

I do not think there is something right out of the box. Two ideas:

1. CouchDB on a memory filesystem. Set up a ramdisk, or tmpfs mount, and configure the CouchDB `database_dir` and `view_index_dir` to point to there.
2. [PouchDB](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb) is porting CouchDB to the browser IndexedDB standard. You did not say which language and environment you are using, but if you can run Node.js, this might be worth looking into. PouchDB has good momentum and I think it will be running in Node.js soon (perhaps through jsdom or some other library. Note, this does not get you the full solution; but you have expanded your question to "are there in-memory IndexedDB implementations for Node.js" for which the answer is either "yes" or "soon," given its adoption trajectory.

Comment: I avoided using the word "mock", because what I really want is to run against real database, just with a faster backend (not necessarily persistent). Mocks are never 100% compatible, and accurate mocks are expensive to maintain.

Comment: Right. You need a "mock" that is so faithful to the real thing that is it, in fact, the real thing. That's good testing. Unfortunately I haven't any better ideas than the two half-answers I listed (which don't add up to a whole).

Answer (score 2):

Found this: https://github.com/RipcordSoftware/AvanceDB - it supports different platforms and seems to be a serious effort.

Comment: this is really, really useful! let's hope it will get more momentum.

Answer (score 2):

Rather late to the party, but I've had great success using [`pouchdb-server`](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server), based on the aforementioned PouchDB project (a JavaScript implementation of CouchDB). It can run against a variety of back-ends, including an in-memory back-end. That means you can run

```
pouchdb-server --in-memory
```

to get an in-memory CouchDB-compatible server. There's several other command-line options to explore, too.

I think it is able to run the entire CouchDB test suite, so I'd guess it is fairly unlikely you'd run into too many implementation differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem... for tests i just don't want to setup a couchdb... i just want to have some memory stuff, as easy as possible.

What did i do:
* I create a memory CouchDB Connector => it's just a very simple implementation of "org.ektorp.CouchDbConnector"
* By spring i wire the CouchDbConnection-Implementation which i need => when i use it for my dev-tests i wire my memory CouchDB Connector, if i want to connect to a real CouchDb i use the usual connector => org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector

The only problem is, that "org.ektorp.CouchDbConnector" has more than 50 methods, which must be implemented. For my issues it was enough to implemented just a few of these methods. Depends on your testcases.

Answer (score -1):

[memorydb](https://github.com/go-kivik/memorydb) is a partial (in-progress) in-memory implementation of CouchDB to be used with [Kivik](https://github.com/flimzy/kivik), which can be run as a stand-alone server.

Not all functionality is implemented yet.